# C# logical operation question

Tags: c#, evaluation, operator-keyword

why this is true:

```
(true | false & false)
```

and this is false:

```
(true | false && false)
```

in my mind should be the oposite..

Comment: `|` and `&` are bitwise operators (that happen to be defined for bools as well) - use `||` and `&&` for logical operations including short-curcuiting.

Comment: That's the reason why I always explicitly add braces in such situations ;-)

Comment: @delnan: Terminology nitpick: `|` and `&` are defined for integral types and for bool. For integral types they are bitwise operators; for bool they are logical operators without short-circuiting.

Comment: @Martinho: Well, assuming the definition `true = 1` and `false = 0`, both work ;) But point taken.

Answer (score 15):

They bind as:

```
true | (false & false)  // true
```

and

```
(true | false) && false  // false
```

I would avoid writing code which relies on these rules though - it's obviously unclear to the reader :)

For reference, see section 7.3.1 of the C# 4 language specification, which shows `&` having higher precedence than `|` (hence the first result) and `|` having higher precedence than `&&` (hence the second result).

Comment: damn, both of you were faster. Yes, it is 7.2.1.

Comment: Also: my rule of thumb: **never learn the precedence table**; use brackets instead. Save your brain for stuff that matters.

Comment: It's 7.3.1 in the C# 4 spec :)

Comment: Yes, it's advisable to use brackets to make your code easier to read.

Comment: d'oh! I checked 1.1 and 3.0 - sigh

Answer (score 3):

This is because of operator precedence [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`&` has priority to `|` which has priority to `&&`, so your expressions are evaluated as

```
(true | (false & false)) = (true | false) = true
```

and

```
((true | false) && false) = (true && false) = false
```

See [the reference of C# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) containing there precedence for more information.